# can you use wildcards in the middle of directories in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

According to: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges, you can list wildcards for all subdirectories:

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
      - docker/scripts/*
      - dockerfiles/**/*
      - more_scripts/*.{rb,py,sh}
      - "**/*.json"
```

but what about if you want to include multiple directories? say I have a folder stucture like this:

```
server-a-files/**/*
server-b-files/**/*
server-c-files/**/*
```

etc.  would something like this work?

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
    changes:
      - server-*-files/**/*
```

or would I need to do something like this:

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
    changes:
      - server-{a,b,c}-files/**/*
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a wildcard in the middle of a path segment. GitLab uses Ruby's [fnmatch](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) for testing glob patterns for `changes:`.

```rb
irb(main):002:0> File.fnmatch('server-*-files/**/*', 'server-a-files/foo/bar')
=> true
```